# How to compare multiple variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

At the moment I need a method to analyze data that I have and it would be of great help if you could collaborate with me. The data is shown as in the following example:

```
> glimpse(test)
Rows: 559
Columns: 4
$ Host.H <chr> "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Human", "Hu…
$ Host.I <chr> NA, "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermedia…
$ Host.B <chr> NA, "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", "Bat", NA, "Bat", "Bat"…
$ Host.C <chr> NA, "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Consensus", "Co…
```

These data correspond to organisms derived from bats, an intermediate, human and replica (Host.B, Host.I, Host.H and Host.C). It can be found that they aren't complete in all the cells, there are some with unavailable data as N.A. Therefore, my goal is that if in all the variables there is data among (Host.B = Bat, Host.I = Intermediate, Host.H = Human and Host. C = Consensus) it is assigned to a new column called "type" as "Conserved", while if there is missing data among the variables (Host.B = N.A, Host.I = Intermediate, Host.H = N.A and Host.C = Consensus) it is identified as "Shared" and if there is only one data in the column (Host.B = Bat, Host.I = N.A, Host.H = N.A and Host.C = N.A) as "Unique".

For this purpose I have designed the following script:

```
test <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Type = case_when(
    all_eq(c(Host.H = Human, Host.C = Consensus, Host.B = Bat, Host.I = Intermediate), na.rm = T ~ "Conserved",
    all_neq(c(Host.H = Human, Host.C = Consensus, Host.B = Bat, Host.I = Intermediate), na.rm = T)) ~ "Unique",
    TRUE ~ "Shared"
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for the goal I need. For this reason, if you have a more feasible way to perform this operation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your data by pasting `dput(data)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` to count number of non-NA value in a dataframe. Based on that `count` you can assign `Type` column.

```
library(dplyr)

test <- test %>%
  mutate(count = rowSums(!is.na(.[c('Host.H', 'Host.I', 'Host.B', 'Host.C')])), 
         Type = case_when(count == 4 ~ 'Conserved', 
                          count > 1 ~ 'Shared', 
                          count == 1 ~ 'Unique'))
```

You may drop the `count` column from the output by including `%>% select(-count)`.

Comment: Hi Ronak, how can I count the columns of Host.H, Host.B, Host.I and Host.C only without using the "select" function? Your example code counts all the NA in the columns that I don't want.

Comment: @DiegoMunoz Well in the `glimpse` there were only 4 columns showed so I did not select columns specifically. See the updated answer if it helps.